# Deserialize JSON Array with JSON.NET JArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize my JSON Array using Newtonsoft JSON.NET nugget:

Here's the code:

```
 private List<TemplateTypesObj> getTemplateTypes(JArray array)
    {
        List<TemplateTypesObj> templateTypes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TemplateTypesObj>>(array);

        return templateTypes;
    }
```

The only issue is that DeserializeObject takes String, not an JArray object. I can do `array.toString()` but I'm not sure if that is a proper way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because a JArray doesn't really need deserializing. It's not a string/binary representation of an object (which is something you'd deserialize). It's already an object which represents your JSON. You can use it like an object - iterate through it, extract individual items from it.

Check out the docs at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jarray.htm - there are methods in there which I'm sure could be used to achieve the conversion you want.

Comment: Oh, I get you. Thought It would be easier just to conver JArray to List than normal JSON String tbh.

Comment: If you're receiving a JSON string in the first place, it's probably easier to directly deserialize it to your final type using DeserializeObject() than to add the extra step of converting to JArray and then to the type.

Comment: Yup, that's what I've end up doing. No fancy code :(

Comment: ok well if it works and the answer has helped you please upvote / mark as accepted. Thanks :-)